# вечный цикл на С

Tags: c, циклы

есть рекурентная последовательность:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

первый член последовательности y_1 = a (a вводится с клавиатуры)

нужно найти первый член последовательности, для которого выполняется неравенство:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот мой код:

```
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    double a ,x, E, difference;
    printf("введите а: ");
    scanf("%lf", &a);
    printf("введите x: ");
    scanf("%lf", &x);
    printf("введите E: ");
    scanf("%lf", &E);
    double y_i = a, previous = y_i;
    while(1) {
        y_i = 0.5 * (previous + (x / previous));
        difference = fabs(pow(y_i, 2) - pow(previous, 2));
        if (difference < E) {
            printf("первый член для которого difference меньше чем %lf = %lf", E, y_i);
            break;
        }
        else {
            previous = y_i;
            printf("%lf \n", y_i);
            continue;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

вопрос: для a = 10, x = 5, E = 0.1 получается вечный цикл(с определенного момента выводится только 2,236068), хотя в онлайн компиляторе такого не происходит и выводит правильный результат(первый член для которого difference меньше чем 0.100000 = 2.236070). почему так получается ? спасибо

Comment: Какой компилятор, какая ОС? И не перепутали ли `a` и `x` в примере?

Comment: стандартный компилятор code:blocks (не помню как называется), 10 винда. да, в примере а = 10, х = 5. спасибо. посмотрел, компилятор GNU GCC Complier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

проблема тут

```
printf("введите а: ");
scanf("%lf",  &a);
printf("введите x: ");
scanf("%lf", &x);
printf("введите E: ");
scanf("%lf", &E);
```

E считывается как 0

если сразу задать

```
double a = 10, x = 5, E = 0.1, difference;
```

то код отрабатывает без зацикливания

**Вот ваша реальная проблема:**

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
```

раз `LC_ALL` то и ввод с плавающей запятой требуется по-русски, т.е. `0,1`, а не `0.1`

Comment: большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
```

Как только вы от него откажетесь, так сразу оно перестанет требовать вводить данные с запятой, а не с точкой :)

Или не отказывайтесь, но вводите 0.1 - как **0,1** - обратите внимание на запятую.

Comment: Или после установки локали вызвать `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C");`

Comment: @EOF Ну да, логично :)

Comment: большое спасибо!